# Math Proof (Proving there exists) : For every integer $k$, there exists an integer $m$ such that $\forall n \in \Bbb N$, we have $0 \leq m + k < n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am not sure how to go about proving this problem.

For every integer $k$, there exists an integer $m$ such that $\forall n \in \Bbb N$, we have
$$0 \leq m + k < n$$.

Would I just show that there exists a integer $m$, by moving $k$ over to the other side? But then I am not sure that shows for all $n$ and $k$.

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: I would say, just choose $m=-k$, and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

What is required here is, given any integer $k$, to construct an integer $m$ having the given property "$0 \leq m+k < n$ for all integers $n \geq 1$". We note that if $m := -k$, then $m$ is an integer by definition and $m+k = 0 < n$ for all integers $n \geq 1$. This proves the claim.

Comment: thank you. thus we showed that if m=-k it will always be an integer that is always less than n. I got it.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi, tskgreen, my pleasure.